How Do I Have Visual Studio Code Open a Browser That Is Within WSL (Ubuntu-22.04)?
I am currently working on a web development exercise where running the tests will execute a series of operations and one of these is opening a web browser.
I started using WSL (Ubuntu-22.04) more recently and when using VS code through here, it will launch the browser on the Windows side. Normally this isn't a problem in the past but in this case it is because I need to open chrome and within the Linux environment.
I have installed Chrome on this Ubuntu sub-system located in /snap/bin/chromium and I have tried various methods from past answers (though none were WSL specific) and it still seems to launch on my Windows browser instead of that browser located there.
Does anyone know or can point me in the right direction of overcoming this?
